# Freemarker template currency symbol encoding issue

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, freemarker

Using freemarker template with java is producing an incorrect currency symbol. 
Expecting `$` however getting `¤`

I've tried setting the `encoding` and `outputEncoding` on the freemarkerConfig with no luck

```java
    public String processTemplate(String freemarkerTemplate, Object model, Locale locale) throws IOException, TemplateException {
        try {
            this.freemarkerConfig.setSetting("locale", locale.getLanguage());
            this.freemarkerConfig.setSetting("time_zone", "EST");
        } catch (TemplateException e) {
            log.warn("Failed to set locale {} for freemarker template.", locale.getLanguage(), e);
        }
        //freemarkerConfig.setEncoding(locale, "UTF-8");
        //freemarkerConfig.setOutputEncoding("UTF-8");
        Template template = freemarkerConfig.getTemplate(freemarkerTemplate);
        //template.setOutputEncoding("UTF-8");
        return FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(template, model);
    }
```

Also have tried adding the `<#ftl encoding="utf-8">` to my template file without any difference.

**EDIT**

This is how I'm using the currency function:  `${amountValue?string.currency}`

Comment: Haven't found a fix for this yet but I a workaround by formatting in JAVA first using: `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale).format(amountValue)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an encoding issue. The ¤ character is called the currency sign, and Java number format prints it if it doesn't know the actual currency. The reason it doesn't know it is that you set the FreeMarker `locale` setting to `locale.getLanguage()` (like "en"), instead of `locale.toString()` (like "en_US", which also contains a country), and the language is not enough to decide the currency, it's the country that decides that.

Also, if you can, avoid `setSetting`, and call the strongly typed methods, like `freemarkerConfig.setLocale(locale)`, `freemarkerConfig.setTimeZone(timeZone)`, etc.

Comment: Didn't even realize I'm messing up the settings. 
Thanks for the great answer. :thumbs_up: